# Get 2 words in every array value

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I have code like this one

```
$words2= 'If you want to have a preformatted block within a list, indent by eight spaces.';

$forbiddenwords=array("word1","word2");

foreach($words2 as $b=>$v)
{
    if(in_array($v, $forbidden) ){
    unset($words2[$b] );

    }
}

$words2 = array_values($words2);

$words2=implode(' ',$words2);

$words2 = implode(' ',array_chunk(mb_split('\s', $words2), 2));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($words2);
echo "</pre>";
```

What I want is to create an array that every value of it contain 2 words from the string. The code above doesn't work -implode() not working with associative arrays- also the result that I'm trying to have is like that

```
array (
$words2[0]=>'If you'
$words2[1]=>'you want'
$words2[1]=>'want to'
...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are over-complicating things, both when removing blacklisted words and when constructing the arrays of pairs of words.

To remove blacklisted:

```
$inputWords = mb_split('\s+', 'If you want to have a preformatted block...');
$forbiddenWords = array("want", "have");

$filtered = array_diff($inputWords, $forbiddenWords); // removes blacklisted
```

To join every 2 filtered words into a string:

```
$pairs = array_chunk($filtered, 2); // array of arrays
$pairs = array_map(function($a) { return implode(' ', $a); }, $pairs);
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/SD0nJ9)**.